# Displaying date in JTextField while User enters numbers (Java)

Tags: java, swing, date

I'm a begginner in programming and I have simple program, which calculates something, using dates in the calculation formula.

So, I have two fields:

`JTextField startDate` - for entering first date, and `JTextField endDate` - for second date.

When user enters any values to that fields, I'm using `getText()` and then these values are converted to `SimpleDateFormat DATE = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy")` by using `DATE.parse("value from getText()")`. After that we can do with our new `Date` value whatever we want.

**What is the problem and what I want to do.** The date input looks like:

[image]

But 
visually it's not good for me. I want to do some kind of "auto date input". For example: user enters "09052017", but in the `JTextField` we see "09.05.2017", or user just enters "09", but in the field we see "09.", then "0905", but in the field we have "09.05.". So, the user enters `09052017`, but in the field we see:

[image]

How to realize that?

Comment: One possible solution http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JCalendar](https://toedter.com/jcalendar/). It is like a small calendar which will open in you gui and user can select the desired date.

To use a JCalendar, you need to import a `.jar` file in your project that is provided in the link provided above.

JCalendar looks like

[image]

Additionally you can change the format of the date to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to format dates however you want.  You have wildcards for the date parameters and then you can add separating characters like slashes or dots.

```
String pattern = "MM.dd.yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat (pattern);
String t = sdf.format (new Date());
```